# how to use the option nameServerSet using the google Cloud DNS API

Tags: google-cloud-dns

If I am right the `nameServerSet` could give me the option to specify the DNS servers to handle request for a domain, this could be useful if I want to use my own domains like for doing white label.

From the docs: [nameServerSet](https://cloud.google.com/dns/api/v1/managedZones#nameServerSet)

> **nameServerSet**  Optionally specifies the NameServerSet for this
>   ManagedZone. A NameServerSet is a set of DNS name servers that all
>   host the same ManagedZones. Most users will leave this field unset.

But what are the posible "string" values to use?

Comment: If you've managed to find an answer elsewhere I'm interested to know. It's strange how the documentation is just totally vacant, but they've only recently begun offering whitelabel DNS. At this point I'm just creating the zone with default NSes, then submitting a `change` to replace them with my own.

Comment: Unfortunately haven't found anything yet, could you provide a link about the whitelabel offering?

Comment: It doesn't look like they've officially announced it yet, I think we're in early access and maybe I'm not supposed to talk about it? [woops] If you've got a GCP sales rep you might be able to wrangle access from them, otherwise the usual timeline from EA to release seems to be a couple months.

Comment: So, fun fact: They're not doing this and I'm up a certain creek without a paddle. `:I`

Comment: I don't have a GCP rep, unfortunately after sending couple of emails, I never got any answer, probably they plan to offer the service in a near future how knows.