# How to set default namesevers for a Google Cloud DNS zone?

Tags: gcloud, nameservers, google-cloud-dns

I'm using Google's CloudDNS API to batch upload a bunch of domains to Google Cloud. I want to be able to override the default nameservers that Google randomly assigns for example

- ns-cloud-e1.google.com
- ns-cloud-e2.google.com
- ns-cloud-e3.google.com
- ns-cloud-e4.google.com

to

- n1.domain.com
- n2.domain.com
- n3.domain.com

I've noticed that Google's CloudDNS API's documentation references the following

**nameServerSet** (string) -

> Optionally specifies the NameServerSet for this ManagedZone. A
> NameServerSet is a set of DNS name servers that all host the same
> ManagedZones. Most users will leave this field unset.

Though when trying to use this property via the CloudDNS, I receive a response from the API saying that the data provided through data is invalid. I passed through in the format of `"n1.domain.com.,n2.domain.com.,n3.domain.com."`. I've also tried passing through an array of nameservers and a RecordResourceSet class from the Google PHP package, with no avail.

Is this the correct format I should be following or is it not possible to pre-define the nameservers when the managed zone is created and instead have to do this after the zone is created?

Code example below, $cloud_dns->service is an instance of `Google_Service_Dns`

```php
$cloud_dns->service->managedZones
    ->create(
         'blah',
         new Google_Service_Dns_ManagedZone([
             'dnsName'       => $dns_name_formatted,
             'name'          => 'app-' . $domain_name,
             'description'   => 'Batch Uploaded Domain',
             'nameServerSet' => 'n1.domain.com.,n2.domain.com.,n3.domain.com.'
           ]),
        );
```

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet you're running against API ? Please update your question with the code details.

Comment: @Wojtek_B have done so!

Comment: Have you tried without the dots at the end of the domain name ? Like this `n1.domain.com,n2.domain.com,n3.domain.com`

Comment: Unfortunately, I receive the following "Invalid value for 'entity.managedZone.nameServerSet': 'n1.domain.com,n2.domain.com,n3.domain.com',

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to consider filing this issue with Google's public [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187241).

You're not the [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36582739/how-to-use-the-option-nameserverset-using-the-google-cloud-dns-api) to encounter this and that question is 4 years old and remains unanswered :-(

Regardless of language SDK, the underlying call can be tested using Google's [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer) and specifically [ManagedZones:create](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/reference/v1/managedZones/create) which conveniently includes the relevant API method. You can plug in your values and try it out (securely) within the browser, or:

```sh
NAME="yourdomain-com"
DNS="yourdomain.com." # Must end with a period (.)

TOKEN=$(gcloud auth print-access-token)

curl \
--request POST \
--header "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" \
--header "Accept: application/json" \
--header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--data "{\"nameServerSet\":\"n1.domain.com.,n2.domain.com.\",\"name\":\"${NAME}\",\"dnsName\":\"${DNS}\",\"description\":\"\"}" \
"https://dns.googleapis.com/dns/v1/projects/${PROJECT}/managedZones"
```

I tried to craft a request using `nameServerSet` using the API directly and am unable. It's thus not a language SDK issue but a question of whether|how this property may be set.

It's somewhat interesting to note that you can't set name servers when creating zones through the console ([link](https://console.cloud.google.com/net-services/dns/zones/new/create)). But, you may subsequently change them. The console POSTs to `ManagedZone:changes`, e.g.:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/dns/v1beta2/projects/${PROJECT}/managedZones/${NAME}/changes
{
  "additions": [
    {
      "name": "...",
      "type": "NS",
      "ttl": 21600,
      "rrdatas": [
        "ns-cloud-d1.googledomains.com.",
        "ns-cloud-d3.googledomains.com.",
        "ns-cloud-d4.googledomains.com."
      ]
    }
  ],
  "deletions": [
    {
      "name": "...",
      "type": "NS",
      "ttl": 21600,
      "rrdatas": [
        "n1.domain.com.",
        "n2.domain.com.",
        "n3.domain.com."
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```